# Runtime Error 9 while selecting the Sheet in ActiveWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I get run time error 9 while running the below sub routine at the line Sheets(2).Select. I checked in the immediate window for Activeworkbook.Name I get the correct workbook name. But not sure why subscript out of range error is thrown. ThisWorkbook has only sheet1, so I am guessing it is somehow referring to ThisWorkbook not ActiveWorkbook. How to correct it. I have also tried alternate lines of code it did not help.   ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Sheets(1).Next.Select
The subroutine will clear formats if A5 value is blank in all workbooks.
[image]

```
Sub REReplace()
Dim Folder As String, FileName As String
Dim tWB, w As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set tWB = ThisWorkbook
Folder = "C:\New\test"
FileName = Dir(Folder & "\*.xlsx")
Do
    Workbooks.Open Folder & "\" & FileName
    FileName = Dir
Loop Until FileName = ""

    For Each w In Workbooks
    If Not w Is ThisWorkbook Then
        w.Activate
        Sheets(2).Select
        
        If Sheets(2).Range("A5").Value = "" Then
        Sheets(2).Range("A5").Select
        Sheets(2).Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.ClearFormats
        Sheets(2).Range("A3").Select
        End If
        
        w.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If
Next w
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The below code will replace the last value of the document number from 1 to 2 e.g BCR-98946210371-001 to BCR-98946210371-002 and removes formatting from cells D1:D8 in sheet1. Now I have additional requirement in sheet2 as posted in my question. I need to clear formats from row A5:Q5 if its blank.

```
**********Combined code in sheet1 and sheet2**********

Sub REReplace()
Dim Folder As String, FileName As String
Dim tWB, w As Workbook
Dim n As String
Dim j As String, Ex As String, Con, l As String
Dim o As Integer, p As Integer, u As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    j = "2"
    Set tWB = ThisWorkbook
    Folder = "C:\new\test"
    FileName = Dir(Folder & "\*.xlsx")
    Do
        Workbooks.Open Folder & "\" & FileName
        FileName = Dir
    Loop Until FileName = ""

        For Each w In Workbooks
            If Not w Is ThisWorkbook Then
                With w
                   .Activate
                   If .Sheets.Count >= 2 Then
                   With Sheets(1)
                    'Here You can Add More Code per Sheet
                    .Activate

                     l = .Range("B1").Value
                     o = Len(l)
                     p = Right(l, 1)
                     u = o - p
                     Ex = Left(l, u)
                     Con = Ex & j
                    .Range("B1").Value = Con
                    .Range("D1:D8").ClearFormats
                    
                  End With
                
                   
                   With Sheets(2)
                    'Here You can Add More Code per Sheet
                    .Activate
                        If .Range("A5").Value = "" Then
                           .Range("A5").Select
                           .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).ClearFormats
                           .Range("A3").Select
                            
                        End If
                   End With
                            .Sheets(1).Activate
                        .Close SaveChanges:=True
                    End If
                End With
            End If
         Next w

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I would do, in order to help easy with your code, will add and if before the error, with the Sheets.Count. Also, the `if` did not work for me, so I added `Thisworkbook.Name` See below:

```
For Each w In Workbooks
    If Not w.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        With w
           .Activate
            If .Sheets.Count >= 2 Then
             'Here you can add more Sheets
                With Sheets(1)
                    'Here You can Add More Code per Sheet
                    .Activate
                    '...
                End With
                With Sheets(2)
                    .Activate
                    If .Range("A5").Value = "" Then
                        .Range("A5").Select
                        .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).ClearFormats
                        .Range("A3").Select
                    End If
                End With
                .Close SaveChanges:=True
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next w
```

Try to Use `With` Command, it helps to read the code and also make it faster.

Other thing, try to avoid `.Select`, please read this remarkable post and learn how to manage it. [How to Avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: It worked. However, the workbook stays open even though .Close SaveChanges:=True was present in the code.

Comment: I had to remove stop then it worked. Workbook is saved and closed.

Comment: How do I merge both these into one subroutine. For Each w In Workbooks
        If Not w Is ThisWorkbook Then
            w.Activate
            Set w = ActiveWorkbook
            Sheets(1).Select
            Range("A1").Select
            n = k
            Range("B13").Value = n
            l = Range("B1").Value
            o = Len(l)
            p = Right(l, 1)
            u = o - p
            Ex = Left(l, u)
            Con = Ex & j
            Ex = Left(l, u)
            Con = Ex & j
            Range("B1").Value = Con
            Range("D1:D8").ClearFormats
end if Next w

Comment: I need to merge the sub routine in the above comment with the sub routine I posted.

Comment: Add comments in the code where to put more code per File and the more code per sheet.

Comment: I have updated my original post with old code in sheet1 and new code in sheet2. After both the codes are merged. I run the combined code on each workbook in the folder using Do Loop.

Comment: I have merged both the codes and posted in my original post. It worked without any errors.